# Create vCard file from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to create vCard from SQL Server (v 2012) and after that I want to send it via email from db_mail. To create vCard file I am using xp_cmdshell. I prepare all cmd commands in one varchar variable and the execute xp_cmdshell using that variable as command text. The result is not as I expect. I receive only first line of the text in the generated vCard file. When I take the same text and run it as batch file the vCard file is created properly.

```
DECLARE @iIDUser AS INT = 1;
DECLARE @iIDContact AS INT = 1;

DECLARE @iResult AS INT;
DECLARE @sExecute_vCardText AS VARCHAR(8000) = '';
DECLARE @crlf CHAR(2) = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10);
DECLARE @sFile VARCHAR(1000) = ' >> C:\Databases\_tmp_sql\PES_ERP\User.vcf';

SELECT @sExecute_vCardText = @sExecute_vCardText 
    + @crlf + 'ECHO ' + 'BEGIN:VCARD' + ' > C:\Databases\_tmp_sql\PES_ERP\User.vcf' 
+ @crlf + 'ECHO ' + 'VERSION:2.1' + @sFile 
+ @crlf + 'ECHO ' + 'CATEGORIES:' + 
    + ISNULL(Cnt.ContactRole_Name_en,'')  
    + ',' + ISNULL(Cnt.ContactRelationshipType_Name_en,'') 
    + ',' + ISNULL(Cnt.VisibilityType_Name_en,'')  + @sFile 
+ @crlf + 'ECHO ' + 'FN:' + ISNULL(Cnt.ContactTitle_Name_en,'')  + @sFile 
    + ' ' + ISNULL(Cnt.Name,'') + ' ' + ISNULL(Cnt.Surname,'') 
+ @crlf + 'ECHO ' + 'N:' + ISNULL(Cnt.Surname,'')  + @sFile 
    + ';' + ISNULL(Cnt.Name,'') 
    + ';' + ISNULL(Cnt.ContactTitle_Name_en,'')  + @sFile 
+ @crlf + 'ECHO ' + 'TITLE:' + ISNULL(Cnt.JobTitle,'')  + @sFile 
+ @crlf + 'ECHO ' + 'BDAY:' + ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(16),Cnt.BirthDate,112),'')  + @sFile 
+ @crlf + 'ECHO ' + 'BIRTH:' + ISNULL(Cnt.BirthMunicipality_Name,'')  + @sFile 
+ @crlf + 'ECHO ' + 'TEL;TYPE=work:' + ISNULL(Cnt.Business_Phone,'')  + @sFile 
+ @crlf + 'ECHO ' + 'TEL;TYPE=work:' + ISNULL(Cnt.Business_Phone2,'')  + @sFile 
+ @crlf + 'ECHO ' + 'TEL;TYPE=work,cell:' + ISNULL(Cnt.Business_Mobile,'')  + @sFile 
+ @crlf + 'ECHO ' + 'TEL;TYPE=work,cell:' + ISNULL(Cnt.Business_Mobile2,'')  + @sFile 
+ @crlf + 'ECHO ' + 'TEL;TYPE=work,fax:' + ISNULL(Cnt.Business_FAX,'')  + @sFile 
+ @crlf + 'ECHO ' + 'ADR;TYPE=work:;;' + ISNULL(Cnt.Business_Address,'') + ';' + ISNULL(Cnt.Business_City,'') + ';' + ISNULL(Cnt.Business_Municipality_Name,'') + ' (' + ISNULL(Cnt.Business_Region_Name,'') + ') ' + ';' + ISNULL(Cnt.Business_CAP,'') + ';' + ISNULL(CASE WHEN (@iIDLanguage = 40001) THEN Cnt.Business_Country_Name_en WHEN (@iIDLanguage = 40002) THEN Cnt.Business_Country_Name_it WHEN (@iIDLanguage = 40003) THEN Cnt.Business_Country_Name_de WHEN (@iIDLanguage = 40004) THEN Cnt.Business_Country_Name_fr ELSE Cnt.Business_Country_Name_en END,'') + @sFile 
+ @crlf + 'ECHO ' + 'EMAIL;TYPE=internet,work,pref:' + ISNULL(Cnt.Business_EMail,'')  + @sFile 
+ @crlf + 'ECHO ' + 'EMAIL;TYPE=internet,work:' + ISNULL(Cnt.Business_EMail2,'')  + @sFile 
+ @crlf + 'ECHO ' + 'TEL;TYPE=home:' + ISNULL(Cnt.Home_Phone,'')  + @sFile 
+ @crlf + 'ECHO ' + 'TEL;TYPE=home,cell:' + ISNULL(Cnt.Home_Mobile,'')  + @sFile 
+ @crlf + 'ECHO ' + 'ADR;TYPE=work:;;' + ISNULL(Cnt.Home_Address,'') + ';' + ISNULL(Cnt.Home_City,'') + ';' + ISNULL(Cnt.Home_Municipality_Name,'') + ';' + ISNULL(Cnt.Home_CAP,'') + ';;'  + @sFile 
+ @crlf + 'ECHO ' + 'EMAIL;TYPE=internet,home:' + ISNULL(Cnt.Home_EMail,'')  + @sFile 
+ @crlf + 'ECHO ' + 'NOTE:' + ISNULL(Cnt.Note,'')  + @sFile 
+ @crlf + 'ECHO ' + 'REV:' + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar,GETDATE(),120),'-',''),':',''),' ','T') + 'Z'  + @sFile 
+ @crlf + 'ECHO ' + 'END:VCARD'  + @sFile 
FROM 
    dbo.fun_Contacts(@iIDUser) AS Cnt 
WHERE 
    (Cnt.IDContact = @iIDContact);

EXEC @iResult = master..xp_cmdshell @sExecute_vCardText;

select @iResult as a;
```

Can anyone give me a clue where I do something wrong?

Comment: sp_cmdshell is deactivated by default and that with a good reason. YOur architecture says "please own me, I am a badly run sql server". It would be a lot better to do that stuff where you run your logic - in the application.

Comment: I know this [TomTom](http://stackoverflow.com/users/285465/tomtom), I have to use this kind of generation. This is a requirement of the designer. I can do it by CLR, by this is forbidden by the designer. So I have to stick to this method. Also I am very quirious why I can not get expected results.

Comment: Well, whatever you do remembe that you have a critical issue here - you have a hardcoded vcf file name. THat is bad - 2 calls to the SP at the same time will result in overlapping file access.

Comment: Yes, you are right [TomTom](http://stackoverflow.com/users/285465/tomtom). My fault. I forget to mention that this is only for demonstration. In real code this will be a unique parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Why all the ECHO commands?**

It makes the code more complicated.

Here is a re-write creating just a formatted string.  Please check the syntax.

```
-- Declare variables
DECLARE @CrLf CHAR(2) = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10);
DECLARE @SqlStmt varchar(max) = '';

-- Make up the string
SELECT @SqlStmt = 
    'BEGIN:VCARD' + @CrLf +
    'VERSION:2.1' + @CrLf +
    'CATEGORIES:' + 
        ISNULL(C.ContactRole_Name_en,'') + ',' + 
        ISNULL(C.ContactRelationshipType_Name_en,'') + ',' + 
        ISNULL(C.VisibilityType_Name_en,'') + @CrLf + 
    'FN:' + 
        ISNULL(C.ContactTitle_Name_en,'') +  ' ' + 
        ISNULL(C.Name,'') + ' ' + ISNULL(C.Surname,'') + @CrLf + 
    'N:' + 
        ISNULL(C.Surname,'') + ';' + 
        ISNULL(C.Name,'') + ';' + 
        ISNULL(C.ContactTitle_Name_en,'')  + @CrLf + 
    'TITLE:' + ISNULL(C.JobTitle,'')  + @CrLf + 
    'BDAY:' + ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(16),C.BirthDate,112),'')  + @CrLf + 
    'BIRTH:' + ISNULL(C.BirthMunicipality_Name,'')  + @CrLf + 
    'TEL;TYPE=work:' + ISNULL(C.Business_Phone,'')  + @CrLf + 
    'TEL;TYPE=work:' + ISNULL(C.Business_Phone2,'')  + @CrLf + 
    'TEL;TYPE=work,cell:' + ISNULL(C.Business_Mobile,'')  + @CrLf + 
    'TEL;TYPE=work,cell:' + ISNULL(C.Business_Mobile2,'')  + @CrLf + 
    'TEL;TYPE=work,fax:' + ISNULL(C.Business_FAX,'')  + @CrLf + 
    'ADR;TYPE=work:;;' + 
        ISNULL(C.Business_Address,'') + ';' + 
        ISNULL(C.Business_City,'') + ';' + 
        ISNULL(C.Business_Municipality_Name,'') + 
        ' (' + ISNULL(C.Business_Region_Name,'') + ') ' + ';' + 
        ISNULL(C.Business_CAP,'') + ';' + 
        ISNULL
        (
            CASE 
                WHEN (@iIDLanguage = 40001) THEN C.Business_Country_Name_en 
                WHEN (@iIDLanguage = 40002) THEN C.Business_Country_Name_it 
                WHEN (@iIDLanguage = 40003) THEN C.Business_Country_Name_de 
                WHEN (@iIDLanguage = 40004) THEN C.Business_Country_Name_fr 
                ELSE C.Business_Country_Name_en END,'')
        ) + @CrLf + 
    'EMAIL;TYPE=internet,work,pref:' + ISNULL(C.Business_EMail,'')  + @CrLf + 
    'EMAIL;TYPE=internet,work:' + ISNULL(C.Business_EMail2,'')  + @CrLf + 
    'TEL;TYPE=home:' + ISNULL(C.Home_Phone,'')  + @CrLf + 
    'TEL;TYPE=home,cell:' + ISNULL(C.Home_Mobile,'')  + @CrLf + 
    'ADR;TYPE=work:;;' + 
        ISNULL(C.Home_Address,'') + ';' + 
        ISNULL(C.Home_City,'') + ';' + 
        ISNULL(C.Home_Municipality_Name,'') + ';' + 
        ISNULL(C.Home_CAP,'') + ';;'  + @CrLf + 
    'EMAIL;TYPE=internet,home:' + ISNULL(C.Home_EMail,'')  + @CrLf + 
    'NOTE:' + ISNULL(C.Note,'')  + @CrLf + 
    'REV:' + 
         REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar,GETDATE(),120),'-',''),':',''),' ','T') + 
         'Z'  + @CrLf + 
    'END:VCARD'  + @CrLf
FROM 
    dbo.fun_Contacts(@iIDUser) AS C 
WHERE 
    (C.IDContact = @iIDContact);
```

I purposely did not do anything with the string yet since I want to cover some design decisions.

1 - A command prompt has a limit of just under 8K (8192 characters).

**This is probably you issue.**  All the extra ECHO's and destinations are exceeding this limit.

Works from a batch file but not from SQL Server.

2 - If you think you are going to exceed this limit, there are a couple of solutions.

A - **Break the commands into separate calls.**  Use a GUID or such to guarantee file uniqueness.  That is if you really need a file output.

B - If you are just emailing the file, **why not use the @attach_query_result_as_file option?**  This option turns the output from a query into a attachment.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx

Like anything in life, fix on issue and create another.  I think the default file attachment size is 1 MB.  You will have to increase this value if the file attachment exceeds the limit.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlagent/archive/2010/11/10/sql-database-mail-send-emails-with-attachment.aspx

C - **This can all be done in SSIS instead of straight T-SQL.**  Both will work.  But SSIS is more flexible when solving very complex problems.

Good luck with your task.